# How do i print out the right Id with my output

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am working with sklearn and pandas and my prediction is coming out as an array without the right id, which has been set as the index.

My code:

```
train = train.set_index('activity_id')
test = test.set_index('activity_id')

y_train = train['outcome']
x_train = train.drop('people_id', axis=1)
x_test = test

model = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_leaf=100)

model.fit(x_train,y_train)


scores = cross_val_score(model, x_train,y_train, cv=10)
print('mean: {:.3f} (std: {:.3f})'.format(scores.mean(), scores.std()), end='\n\n')
print(model.score(x_train,y_train))
#make predictions
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

Any thoughts on how i can get them to print out with the right activity_id list? Thanks!

Comment: You wish to see the correct values next to the predicted values? Maybe also an example of the data you are using. e.g. `y_train.head()` and `x_train.head()`.

Comment: This is not my whole code, just parts i think are relevant to the question, but thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have written I believe you are trying to show your index for x_test next to the y_pred values generated by x_test.

This can be done by turning the numpy array output from `model.predict(x_test)` into a DataFrame. Then we can set the index of the new DataFrame to be the same as that of `x_test`.

Here is an example,

```
df_pred = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, index=x_test.index, columns=['y_pred'])
```

Comment: That would be x_test index next to y_pred(the predicted value) not train, but yes pretty much the gist. I think what works is calling the model with your example. Thanks!